# Android bluetooth socket data transfer and lifecycle

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am currently trying to send some data between two android devices using Bluetooth. I've read plenty of questions regarding bluetooth transfer, sockets, and streams. So far without any luck.
The connection part is working. I get the device address then open a connection using the following :

```
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(myOtherDeviceAdress);
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(myUUID));
socket.connect();
```

And then try to send some data using the `OutputStream`

```
OutputStream mmout=tmp.getOutputStream();
byte[] toSend="Hello World!".getBytes();
mmout.write(toSend);
mmout.flush();
```

On the receiving end:

```
mBluetoothServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("ccv_prototype", UUID.fromString(myUUID));
mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothServerSocket.accept(3 * 1000);
InputStream is = mBluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

And then, different version trying to read the buffer, currently:

```
int c;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
try {
    while ((c = r.read()) != -1) {
        //Since c is an integer, cast it to a char. If it isn't -1, it will be in the correct range of char.
        response.append((char) c);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String result = response.toString();
Log.d("MyTag", "Received String: " + result);
```

My issue here is that if I don't close the `OutputStream`, the receiving end never receives the EOF, but if I add `mmout.close();`, it closes before it even had time to read the message I wanted to send. So far, my only idea is to send a specific token as an EOF but this doesn't sound right.

What did I miss ?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is yes. You should send a specific token to represent EOF. When you do a `read()` operation on a Bluetooth socket, it will either return immediately with some data if there's data ready to be read, or otherwise the `read()` call will block *until* there is some data, *or* some IO exception happens (e.g. the connection drops). This is why you must make use of `Thread`s, particularly for Bluetooth socket read and write operations. What you're attempting to do is rely on the `BufferedReader` returning -1 to indicate "no more data". Sadly, this isn't how it works. The -1 will only happen in the event of some IO exception or the connection closing.

Detection of where your piece of information (i.e. your packet of data) starts and finishes, or indeed determining when an overall communication session is ended, is something that you handle yourself in your own application protocol (or of course an existing protocol) that works over the sockets. This is an important concept with any protocol that works through streaming sockets. A good example to look at is HTTP, which as you know is conventionally used over TCP. Taking a quick look at HTTP will show you (a) how the HTTP protocol uses headers to tell the recipient how many more bytes to expect for the overall HTTP "message", and (b) how HTTP headers are also used to negotiate when the connection should close. What you *cannot* do is attempt to use methods on the sockets themselves to determine when the sender has finished writing a message. Similarly if one end is to be aware that the other end wants to close the connection, that should be negotiated over the application protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. It's clearer in my mind now. Do you have any advice regarding the specific token to send ? I had some issues on this, tried to send a specific 2 bytes token without success. Went in quick and dirty mode and used line feed at the moment, but that's a bit meh.

Comment: If you're just sending simple text strings of arbitrary length, perhaps you could just use the line feed character? Alternatively you could design a more elaborate packet structure, which for example would start with a header field describing the length of the payload. This boils down to exactly what you're wishing to do and what you're trying to exchange across the connection.